# reversing the linkedlist using recursion generating wrong output

Tags: java, linked-list

Is there something wrong with my recursive approach of reversing a linkedlist ? Because I am getting the following output with only 1 getting printed after reversing :

**Original LinkedList:** 
1-->2-->3-->4-->5-->Tail

**Reversed LinkedList Using Recursion:** 
1-->Tail

```
public class ReverseList {

    public static List ReverseRecursion(List head){


        List current = head;

        if(current == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(current.next == null){
            head = current;
            return head;
        }
        ReverseRecursion(current.next);
        current.next.next = current;
        current.next = null;
        return head;

    }



    public static void main (String[] args){

    // Created a Single LinkedList

    List myList = new List(1);
    myList.next = new List(2);
    myList.next.next = new List(3);
    myList.next.next.next = new List(4);
    myList.next.next.next.next = new List(5);

    System.out.println("Original LinkedList: \n"+myList.toString());



    System.out.println("Reversed LinkedList Using Recursion: \n"+ReverseRecursion(myList));

    }
}

class List {
    int value;
    List next;
    public List(int k){
        value = k;
        next = null;
    }

    public String toString(){

        List cur = this;
        String output = "";
        while(cur != null){

            output+=cur.value+"-->";
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return output+"Tail";


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not very far from working code:

```
public static List ReverseRecursion(List head){
    List newHead;

    if(head == null){
        return null;
    }
    if(head.next == null){
        return head;
    }

    newHead = ReverseRecursion(head.next);
    head.next.next = head;
    head.next = null;
    return newHead;
}
```

See [repl](https://repl.it/BVsy)

---

Key points:

1. You don't need `current` at all, `head` is immutable.
2. You should return (and propegate) the "New Head", starting from the deepest recursive call all the way out of the recursion.

Answer (score 2):

In the `ReverseRecursion`,
you never assign the reversed list back to `head`.
Change this line:

```
ReverseRecursion(current.next);
```

To this:

```
head = ReverseRecursion(current.next);
```